# Applying jest coverageThreshold to aggregated report

Tags: node.js, jestjs, code-coverage

## Problem

I have a `Node` project with 2 different `jest` runs that I perform through different `npm` tasks. They both use the same `jest.config.js`, which has a declaration for [`coverageThreshold`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#coveragethreshold-object). I want to apply that threshold to the combined output of the `jest` runs.

*How can I apply a jest coverage threshold to the combined output of multiple test runs?*

---

### Background

For reference, [see the code for the sample project described below here](https://github.com/iterativo/jest-coverage-aggregation)

#### Sample project

To illustrate the problem, assume the project has a single file that looks like this:

*Code under test*

```
# src/index.js

function run(cond) {
  if (cond) {
    return "foo";
  }
  return "bar";
}

module.exports = run;
```

There are also 2 tests in the project:

*Test 1*

```
# src/__tests__/index.group1.test.js

var run = require("../index");

describe("when cond is true", () => {
  it("should return 'foo'", () => {
    expect(run(true)).toEqual("foo");
  });
});
```

*Test 2*

```
# src/__tests__/index.group1.test.js

var run = require("../index");

describe("when cond is false", () => {
  it("should return 'bar'", () => {
    expect(run(false)).toEqual("bar");
  })
});
```

The test coverage `npm` scripts in `package.json` look like this:

```
  "test:group1:coverage": "jest --testPathPattern=group1 --coverage",
  "test:group2:coverage": "jest --testPathPattern=group2 --coverage"
```

Running `npm run test:group1:coverage` generates:

```sh
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |       75 |       50 |      100 |       75 |                   |
 index.js |       75 |       50 |      100 |       75 |                 5 |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Running `npm run test:group2:coverage` generates:

```sh
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |       75 |       50 |      100 |       75 |                   |
 index.js |       75 |       50 |      100 |       75 |                 3 |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

#### Combining coverage reports

[Based on this post](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2418#issuecomment-276056758), I can have a separate npm task like this ...

```
  "test:coverage": "npm run test:group1:coverage && mv ./coverage/coverage-final.json ./coverage/coverage-group1-final.json && npm run test:group2:coverage && mv ./coverage/coverage-final.json ./coverage/coverage-group2-final.json && node ./scripts/map-coverage.js"
```

... to generate a combined coverage report that looks like:

```sh
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

It's all good until this point. The problem arises when trying to apply a coverage threshold to the combined run.

#### Issue

Now, if I add `coverageThreshold` to the `jest.config.js` like this ...

```
module.exports = {
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
        branches: 90,
        functions: 90,
        lines: 90,
        statements: 90,
    },
  },
};
```

... and run `npm run test:coverage`, the tests fails ...

```sh
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |       75 |       50 |      100 |       75 |                   |
 index.js |       75 |       50 |      100 |       75 |                 5 |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for statements (90%) not met: 75%
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for branches (90%) not met: 50%
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for lines (90%) not met: 75%
```

... because it first runs `group1` tests, which on its own fails to get over the coverage threshold set in `jest.config.js`. I want to ignore this threshold for individual runs, and only apply them to the combined report.

#### Note

I know I could split the `jest.config.js` file into separate ones and apply individual coverage thresholds per test group, but I don't want to manage thresholds individually per test group. I want to measure/apply it to the project as a whole, after all individual test runs have been completed and combined.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I'm interested in doing the same thing...

Comment: @Balt unfortunately not

Answer (score 1):

Instead of combining the tasks, combine only the pathPattern.

You can try to create a single task for group1 and group2 something like below

```
"test:commongroup:coverage": "jest --testPathPattern=commonGroup --coverage",
```

where commonGroup is pattern that includes both group1 and group2.